# Why can't visual studio find my image file?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I can't figure out why it can't find my images.  The images are clearly there in the project, and their Build Actions are all set to "Resource".
[image]

If you enlarge, you can see all my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `..\..\Resources\left-icon.png`

Comment: Ah-ha!  I tried using ...\Resources, guess I thought that was the correct way to traverse the folder structure.

Answer (score -2):

Copy to Output Directory should be "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer". I usually use the former.

Comment: I don't think so, because its Build Action is set to Resource.